# Updating "Date Created" after copying files

Tags: windows, powershell, icloud

I have recently used iCloud for Windows (10) to download all pictures from iCloud onto my local machine. I then wanted to create a backup so I copy-pasted all (15'000) pictures onto an external hard disk.

I noticed that because of the copy-paste action, the "Date Created" has -- in hindsight obviously -- been changed from the date that the picture was taken to the date / time of the copy action.

Since the copy-action and before I noticed the change of date, I have put many hours into putting pictures in subfolders, etc. I would now like to put the original date/time back into the metadata.

My idea is to make a dirlisting of the iCloud original archive, returning filename, md5 hash, and Date Created. I then want to write a script (Powershell?) to find the matching file in my subfolders, and update the date.

A few questions:

1. Does this seem like the best approach?
2. Is there a better way to copy photo's in the future, keeping the original Date Created?

Any help into the right direction whether this is a good idea with Powershell, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At least on a same-drive file copy in Windows, the copy will keep the original's modification time (`LastWriteTime` property in PowerShell/.NET) but the creation time (`CreationTime` property) gets set to the current time. Are you sure that's not what happened here? Or you're saying it changed not the attribute but the (EXIF?) tag in the file itself? You say you downloaded the photos "onto my local machine" and then backed them up "onto an external hard disk", so did the copying go iCloud → local drive → external drive, or iCloud → external drive? In which location were the timestamps changed?

Comment: Also, what are you using to determine that the timestamp has changed?  Explorer?  If I open the properties of a JPEG file and select the `Details` tab, under the `Origin` section there is a `Date taken` value, and under the `File` section there `Date created` and `Date modified` values; all three values are the same time.  If I copy and paste that photo and look at its `Details`, the `Date created` value has changed to the current time.  Everything in the `File` section comes from the _filesystem_, not the format-specific metadata, so that change is to be expected based on my previous comment.

Comment: I am using Explorer too. I have downloaded "iCloud for Windows" -- it downloads your iCloud photos to a specified directory (in my case to `C:\Users\pr0no\iCloud` because that is the directory I choose in the iCloud application). If I look at a picture: `Properties > Details > Origin` then all those fields are empty. Under `Properties > Details > File` however, I see `Date Created 08/12/2016 14:22` (the actual date/time the picture was taken) and `Date Modified 05/05/2020 13:17` (the time that the iCloud application downloaded the photo to my local machine).

Comment: But if I now `CTRL-C CTRL-V` this photo to another folder *on the same disk* (I was wrong previously saying that I copied onto an external disk), then the `Date Created` is updated to the time of the `CTRL-V`, but I wanted to preserve this `Date Created`. In the `Properties > Details > Advanced Photo` it says `EXIF version 0221` but all other metadata (except for the aforementioned `File` properties, are empty. So I guess, also per your comment, that this behavior is expected, but then my question is: why did the original iCloud download write the file with `Date Created` from 2016?

Comment: All that to say, I don't _think_ your important timestamps were changed, so no repair should be needed.  This is all just a matter of the difference between the timestamps in file _attributes_ and the timestamps in file _data_.  The one caveat to all this is _unless_ when you said "I would now like to put the original date/time back into the metadata" that "original date/time" _was_ the file attribute timestamp and there never were embedded (I'm assuming JPEG) timestamps.  That would be bad because I would not expect attribute timestamps to be preserved when crossing systems like that.

Comment: The point is, of course, that I would like to still know when a picture was taken, and apparently this iCloud app (my first time using) isn't exporting any other EXIF data. I have used an EXIF viewer and get returned nothing for the pictures downloaded. All I have is this original `Date Created`. Another option would perhaps to iterate through these files, take the `Date Created` and write EXIF data to every image (all jpg) to preserve this date?

Comment: Aha. Well, I think `Date created` is the wrong timestamp to be focusing on for photos because that is file, not photo, metadata. When uploading a file in a browser form or attaching a file to an email, those file attributes are not preserved, and I would not be surprised for a cloud service to do likewise (though a client application would be able to sync them). That is exactly what I would suggest: recover the timestamps from iCloud, write them into a proper EXIF tag for each file, and (optionally) write it to the modification time, too, if you still want that.

Comment: The big question is, did the iCloud files inherit the attributes/timestamps of the original files, or did it set them to the time of upload? Otherwise, do the file names indicate the time they were taken, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

## Manually changing timestamps using PowerShell

To change the Date Created, Date Modified, and Date Accessed file properties using PowerShell, I'd recommend checking out this website [here](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-accessed-modified-created-file-date-timestamp-windows/). It explains how to change the Date Created/Modified/Accessed file properties for a single file, for all files in a given folder, or even for a folder itself. For example:

#### For a single file:

To set the **date created** time for "filename.txt" to 5 December 2012 at, say, 9:57:05 PM, you'd write:

```
(Get-Item "C:\Users\Path_to_file\filename.txt").creationtime=$(Get-Date "05/12/2012 21:57:05")
```

Similarly, to set the **date modified**, you'd write:

```
(Get-Item "C:\Users\Path_to_file\filename.txt").lastwritetime=$(Get-Date "05/12/2012 21:57:05")
```

and for **date accessed** time:

```
(Get-Item "C:\Users\Path_to_file\filename.txt").lastaccesstime=$(Get-Date "05/12/2012 21:57:05")
```

You can event set properties to other properties. For example:
To set the **date created** equal to the **date modified**, you'd write:

```
(Get-Item "C:\Users\Path_to_file\filename.txt").creationtime=$(Get-Item "C:\Users\Path_to_file\filename.txt").lastwritetime
```

#### For all files in a folder named "Test":

```
Get-ChildItem -force 'C:\Users\Path_to_folder\Test\' * | ForEach-Object{$_.CreationTime = ("3 August 2019 17:00:00")}
Get-ChildItem -force 'C:\Users\Path_to_folder\Test\' * | ForEach-Object{$_.LastWriteTime = ("3 August 2019 17:10:00")}
Get-ChildItem -force 'C:\Users\Path_to_folder\Test\' * | ForEach-Object{$_.LastAccessTime = ("3 August 2019 17:10:00")}
```

Note that the `-force` parameter ensures that hidden files are also included. Also, keep in mind that if you want to change each picture's timestamps to that of its own corresponding image (i.e, if you want to intelligently automate the process), you'll need to write a script that takes care of each separate case.

---

## Copy files while preserving timestamps (and more)

The simplest tool to use is Windows' own, built-in tool: `robocopy`. See Microsoft's documentation on the robocopy command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy). You just run the program via the command prompt (with administrator privileges).

For your needs, suppose you have images and videos in their original form (the ones that have all the correct timestamps, etc.) in the folder "Original", located at `"C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Original"`, and you'd like to copy all those images and videos to a folder located on your external hard drive, at `"D:\Pictures\Copied"`. The following command would probably work best:

```
robocopy "C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Original" "D:\Pictures\Copied" *.* /e /copy:DAT /dcopy:DAT /mt:16 /j /xjd /xa:s /r:1 /w:0 /log:"filename_path.txt"
```

Each argument is explained in detail on Microsoft's documentation page for [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), but I'll explain them here too.

1. The 1st argument specifies the path to the source folder. Please note that there are no trailing backslashes! If you include a backslash at the end, `robocopy` won't understand the input.
2. The 2nd argument specifies the path to the destination folder.
3. The 3rd argument can actually be multiple arguments. Here, the `*.*` specifies the file or files to be copied. Since wildcard characters (* or ?) are supported, `*.*` matches *all* files in the source directory (i.e., everything will be copied). `*.*` is the default parameter, so if you want all files to be copied, you don't even need to specify this parameter. If you want to copy, say, all files that end in `.jpg`, you'd write `*.jpg`. Or, if you want to copy, say, just two files `file1.jpg` and `file2.mp4`, you'd write those out explicitly, one after each other, as such `robocopy "C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Original" "D:\Pictures\Copied" file1.jpg file2.mp4 /e /copy:DAT /dcopy:DAT /mt:16 /j /xjd /xa:s /r:1 /w:0 /log:"filename_path.txt"`.
4. The 4th argument `/e` copies subdirectories. This option automatically includes empty directories.
5. `/copy:DAT` specifies which file properties to copy. Here, `D`, `A`, and `T` means that the file's Data, Attributes, and Time Stamps properties will be copied. Refer to robocopy's documentation for more details.
6. `/dcopy:DAT` same as `/copy:DAT` except for folders.
7. `/mt:16` creates multi-threaded copies with 16 threads. You can specify an integer between 1 and 128.
8. `/j` copies using unbuffered I/O (recommended for large files).
9. `/xjd` excludes junction points for directories.
10. `/xa:s` excludes "System" files.
11. `/r:1` specifies the number of retries on failed copies. Here, it's set to 1. The default value is 1,000,000 (one million retries)!
12. `/w:0` specifies the wait time between retries, in seconds. Here, it's set to 0, so 0 seconds are spent waiting.
13. `/log:"filename_path.txt"` writes the status output to the log file.